# Can a positron beam cut through metal?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

Can a positron beam be used to cut through metal?

Comment: What metal? what beam strength?

Comment: All metals, all sizes and any strength beam you choose;-)

Comment: Certainly, so long as you lay in a tachyon containment field and reverse the polarity.

Answer (score 4):

Only superthin metals.

The most intense positron beams that people have constructed may send something like 1 billion positrons per second. If the metal is 1 layer of atoms thick, one could perhaps cut a meter of the material per second. So a sub-micron thickness of the foil could still be enough if the cutting of 1 millimeter of the foil each second were fast enough for you.

Positrons generally penetrate inside the material to the depth comparable to the mean free path which is comparable to several nanometers – like 5 nanometers for various superconductors – and then they annihilate with an electron, leaving a pair of 511 keV photons (gamma rays) from the annihilation.

If there are pores or microscopic cavities in the material, positrons may spend some time over there. So positron beams are being used to detect microscopic pores.

Comment: Wouldn't the destruction of electrons contribute to breaking bonds?  Seems like it's just a matter of time to offset the low particle flux.  Per-particle energy shouldn't matter much either right?

Comment: Would metals that have a sea of electrons still be cutable?

Comment: Lubos, did you mean annihilate with electrons?

Comment: Yes, an electron, fixed! I do think that it is a matter of time, and agree with Brandon. Maybe the conductive electrons wouldn't contribute to the cutting but it could be different with the inner shell electrons. Destroying an electron somewhere must at least change the forces between the nuclei and damage the local crystal structure. I would still prefer to see an experiment over pure theoretical predictions. ;-) In principle, I believe that the cutting should be possible but I also believe that it's not practical enough so that people would be actually using it instead of a knife so far. ;-)

Comment: @Jitter The annihilation gammas are not absorbed close enough to the point of annihilation to be a lot of help. The radiation length for iron is nearly $14 \,\mathrm{g/cm^2}$. That for aluminum is 24. This means that the energy ends up heating up the bulk, not melting the region of the cut. Figures from the *Particle Physics Booklet*.

Comment: I was only originally thinking about the breaking of bonds by annhilation. Wouldn't the future strength of the beam overcome the bulk? I wonder if you could shatter a diamond?

Comment: For large electron speeds the cross-section for electron-atom scattering tends to 0 and this is probably also true for positron-atom scattering. This phenomenon would improve penetration depths.

Comment: Well, right, but at some very high energies, it really doesn't matter much it is positrons - it's just some ionizing radiation. BTW at energies above MeVs or so, it is not right to talk about positron-atom cross section because such high-energy particles interact directly with the elementary particles in the target and they don't care whether those are parts of any bound states.